# Return value dynamically according to method input

Tags: java, methods, parameters

I have extend this method and now the method return string but when memberTypeName = int or double I need to 
return suitable value ,dynamically depend on the membertype name.
how can I do that ?
how to call to this method that return generic value?

```
public static String tRouting(String memberTypeName,String memberName,int cnt) {

        String fieldName = memberName;

        if (memberTypeName == "java.lang.String" ) {
            fieldName = fieldName + "_" + cnt;
        }
        else if (memberTypeName == "int" ) {
            fieldName =  ?
        }
        else if (memberTypeName == "double") {
            fieldName = ?
        }
        return fieldName;
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

T can be Integer, Double or any generic Object type.

```
public static<T> T tRouting(...) {
  T retrn =...;
  ...
  return retrn;
}
```

Comment: And how can I call to this method to get the value?

Comment: and when i try to something like T retrn = cnt;  i got error Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to T

Comment: generic can be only Object type not primitive.